# How to put tablefootnotes on the same page next to each other or in the appendix?

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabularx

I am using `\tablefootnotes` and the respective package(s) (`\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}`) as this is the only way (I know) to put footnotes in a table. It runs perfectly, however, due to the high number of `tablefootnotes` half of the page in my work is full of footnotes as they are listed below each other.

How I thought about solving this problem (as my footnotes are quite short) to put them next to each other  (3 in a line) on the same page or put the `tablefootnotes` in the appendix (on a different page). Unfortunately, I do not know which package to use and how to do it.

```
 \quad\\\quad\\
\textbf{Example 1 } 
\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.8cm}|p{2cm}|p{10cm}}  
        Example A   & Example B &  Example C\tablefootnote{line a, b, c} \\
        Example A\tablefootnote{line a, b, c}   & Example B &  Example C\tablefootnote{line a, b, c} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} \\
```

Any ideas?

Comment: create a _complete_ short example. By the way: do not use something like `\quad\\\quad\\\`  if you need vertical space. There are better commands for this!